# Need to convert Web Form JavaScript to a js file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

Basically I have three functions embedded into my form. I want to move this into a js file that I have already. I did this previously and my pop ups are working but now I want to move one function which executes the onclick event for a download button and the other two functions belonging to my autocomplete extender so I can display the results how I want them.

I have been messing around but I cannot seem to get this working.

This is my JavaScript function in Web Forms

```
function Download() {
    __doPostBack("<%= btnDownload.UniqueID %>", "OnClick");
}
```

This is what I have tried in a js file

```
function Download(button) {
    __doPostBack(button, 'OnClick');
}
```

and this is how I am calling it

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "download", "Download(" & btnDownload.ClientID & ");", True)
```

please can somebody give me a clue to what I am missing and before I forget yes, the file is in my headers

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/importBuyer.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is "OnClick" instead of "onclick"?

Comment: Honestly i do not know but it works in the webform with OnClick

Comment: Not sure about webform, but can you try to use "onclick" in the js file?

Comment: I have tried with the onclick instead of OnClick in the js file and it still does not execute

Comment: Just as a sanity check here: The code presented here does the following: `RegisterStartupScript`, on the server, queues a function to be called when the page is loaded on the client. That function, `Download`, then calls `__doPostBack`, on the client, which does a post back to the server to run the event handler for the Click event on the server. You could, in the place where you're calling `RegisterStartupScript`, just call the event handler directly and save yourself the round trip to the client...

Comment: you are right I can do that, however this is allowing users to download data using the response and httpcontext. Unfortunately when you do this the request is to serve just a csv file. I also needed to update the db to mark X records have been downloaded. The best way i could figure this out was to make the data to be downloaded, update the db, save in a session then do a round trip to get javascript to execute to the click event of a button to actually serve the csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript function `__doPostBack("<%= btnDownload.UniqueID %>", "OnClick");` expect a string as the client ID of the button. So you need to construct the calling script with ID parameter as string as follows:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "download", "Download(""" & btnDownload.ClientID & """);", True)
```

Note the double double-quotes (`""`) above so that the rendered javascript will be like :

```
Download("btnDownloadID");
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much, i have been looking at it for ages did not see i was missing the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

From the example you've posted it seems that the webform way was sending the **UniqueID** and you are sending the **ClientID** 
So you probably only need to send the UniqueID property instead.

I am wondering why should you do that. I would expect you to move from webforms to an API base backend but I can't understand why you want to separate the js integration part while keeping the webforms backend - I would understand if you'd separated the js logic part... not the part that communicates with the webforms

Hoped that helped

Here is a [link](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/the-difference-between-id-clientid-and-uniqueid) describing the difference